# soap refuses to be installed in php

Tags: php, apache

So I have been looking through the answers given about this. As I call on SoapClient I get an error that states:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in...
```

I have gone through what to do so list things up:

I run a **Windows 7** on an **Apache2.2** using **PHP 5.4.28**, phpinfo() does not display anything about soap so I stared in that end.

Removed the ; in front of `extension=php_soap.dll in php.ini`.

libxml Version is 2.7.8.

Restarted first Apache then the entire computer, still nothing on phpinfo().

Tested to change something else in the php.ini to make sure it was correct, immediate response with phpinfo() so correct php.ini.

php_soap.dll is located in php\ext.

What more can I do?

**EDIT**

I found the error on this eventually. In the `php.ini` file as the extensions are listed these needs to have a absolute path to the dll-file the extension is referring to. As I didn't altered the path just keeping the ini-file name it couldn't find it.

so after changing it from `extension=php_soap.dll` to `extension=c:\php\ext\php_soap.dll` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes in php installation there are two `php.ini` files, one for **Apache** and one for **CLI**, make sure that you edited right `php.ini` file.

Comment: I must say I think I did as when I altered other things in that php.ini it had effect in the phpinfo(). What I did was that I turned one thing off and right away that got turned of as I checked.